# XML full stable Joomla package location?

Tags: installation, xml

What's the URL of the xml including latest full stable Joomla packages?
I have found this one (https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml) but there's only updates packages.

I need to get the download link, like the current one:
`https://downloads.joomla.org/cms/joomla3/3-9-26/Joomla_3.9.26-Stable-Full_Package.zip`

Comment: Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a simple link for you to use, but if you visit- https://api.github.com/repos/joomla/joomla-cms/releases the url returns json containing information on joomla releases.

From there you go through the json looking for `draft=false` and `prerelease=false` to find the stable releases. The releases are ordered from newest to oldest.

You can get tarball and zipball urls from the json, but it probably isn't what you are after. Instead once you find the latest release, you go to the url section and follow the link.

For example,

`url: "https://api.github.com/repos/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/41360248"`

Once the link is loaded, parse the contents looking for any `browser_download_url` that doesn't contain patch in the url.

For example,

```
browser_download_url: "https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/releases/download/3.9.26/Joomla_3.9.26-Stable-Full_Package.zip"
```

It's all a bit complicated, but it should yield you with a download url for the latest joomla version .... I hope!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the Latest Joomla! Release here: https://downloads.joomla.org/latest

Comment: Thank you for your answer pe7er! However i'm trying to script Joomla installation process by branch (J3 and J4). So I try to have the download link for each branch.